# focus() doesn't work inside colorbox pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I tried to use `focus` for first input field on the form. but 
it doesn't work.  When I call `attr("id")` for that input it worked.  When I call focus for the same input, I didn't see any 
result.  I also tried to use native Javascript.  Does anyone know how to 
fix that?

Answer (score 7):

You are all misunderstanding the question. When Colorbox opens you can't focus an input field?

...unless you add your focus to the Colobox onComplete key e.g.

```
$('#mydiv a').colorbox({ onComplete:function(){ $('form input:first').focus(); }});
```

You could also bind the focus to an event hook:

```
$('#mydiv a').bind('cbox_complete', function(){
        $('form input:first').focus();
});
```

That should be enough to get started.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful - and actually answered a key aspect of the question.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       // focus on the first text input field in the first field on the page
        $("input[type='text']:first", document.forms[0]).focus();
    });
```

Comment: also can use `(“:text:first”).focus();`

Comment: Thanks but this works only on login form. have you any ideas why it doesn't work on other forms   $("input[id=uname]").val("1300");
  $("input[id=uname]").focus();   i got unfocused field with value= 1300

Answer (score 1):

It may be happening that when your colorbox is opened its focus goes onto the highest element i.e. body of page. use document.activeElement to find that focus went to which element. Then find iframe or id of your colorbox and then set focus on it

Answer (score 0):

Try the first selector,

```
$("form input:first").focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/erick/mMuFc/

Answer (score 0):

I've just stumbled on this problem.

I think it's best to have a single $.colorbox ***opener*** like this:

```
    function showActionForColorBox(
       _url,
       _forFocus
   ) {
   $.colorbox(
         {
            scrolling: false,
            href: _url,
            onComplete: function () {
               idColorboxAjaxIndect1.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               idColorboxAjaxIndect2.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               idColorboxAjaxIndect3.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));
               idColorboxAjaxIndect4.appendTo($('#cboxOverlay'));

               // --> Possible element's ID for focus
               if (_forFocus) {
                  $('#' + _forFocus).focus();
               }
               return;
            },
            onCleanup: function () {
               // TODO: ?
               return;
            },
            onClosed: function () {
               if (shouldReloadPageAfterColorBoxAction) {
                  // --> Should we reload whole page? 
                  shouldReloadPageAfterColorBoxAction = false; // NOTE: To be sure: Reset.
                  window.location.reload(false);
               }
               else if (cbEBillsActionReloadPopup) {
                  // --> Should we reload colorbox
                  cbEBillsActionReloadPopup = false;
                  showActionForColorBox(_url);
               }
               else if (cbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed) {
                  // --> Should we reload colorbox with custom content? 
                  cbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed = false;
                  $.colorbox({ html: setupContentForcbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed });
                  setupContentForcbShouldLoadAnotherContentAfterClosed = '';
               }
               return;
            }
         }
         );

   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
$.colorbox({ 

...,
trapFocus: false
});
```

to disable focus inside colorbox