# couldn't set Cursor in search box

Tags: jquery

I have created a link with the following code in the first file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".add").colorbox();

} );
<script>
<a class="add cboxElement" href="<?php echo base_url();?>product_operation_list/index/<?php echo $row['employee_id'];?>" title="Product Operation List">Click To Assign Operation</a>
```

which opens colorbox with a table styled by jquery dataTable plugin.The code is in other linked file;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#searchOperationTable').dataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers"
} ); 

} );
```

I want to set my cursor in the dataTable's search box by using the following code in the other file;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();
} );
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I tested your code and it works only when used outside of colorbox... but yes in your specific case the focus won't work hmmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem is with colorbox and not with datatables. The problem is probably related to the fact that js tries to put the focus on your input before the content is correctly loaded.

Have you tried to bind the cbox complete event to your focus function?

```
$('.cboxElement').bind('cbox_complete', function(){
        $('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();
});
```

Or else you could change this:

```
$(".add").colorbox();
```

with this:

```
$(".add").colorbox({ 
  onComplete:function(){ $('div.dataTables_filter input').focus(); }
});
```

Check it here for more details : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572692